# How to fetch record from entity which is not having primary key column using JPA or JPQL

Tags: java, oracle

I have table with no primary key or embeddable key (combine two columns to represent data uniquely withing table).

So how can I fetch all records from that table based on one particular column?

```
Select * from player where city = 'MUMBAI'
```

I want to fetch all records from player table but it has no primary key and city is Mumbai.
I want to write JPA or JPQL for this.

Comment: If your two columns identify the row uniquely, and you don't intend to modify their value, then make them a composite ID. But you'd better do the right thing, and add an auto-generated PK to your table.

Comment: JPQL : `select p from player p where p.city = 'MUMBAI`;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a PK to query a table.  Just use a native query:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from player where city = 'MUMBAI'");
List<Object[]> players = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: If I want to achieve it same using CURDRepository of JPA then how it works.

Comment: If you have a different question, then post a new quesion